# What way is faster to populate a list with unique values in Tcl?

Tags: performance, tcl

I want to create a list of unique values. The values are taken from different sources and. There are 2 ways to populate my final list.

Put all the values in and then perform `lrmdups`:

```
set finalList [list ]
foreach selcetion  $selectionList {
    regexp {(\d+):(\d+)} $selection -> start end
    for {set i $start} {$i <= $end} {incr i} {
        lappend finalList $i
    }
}
set finalList [lrmdups $finalList]
```

or check if a value exists in the list, and only if it doesn't add it:

```
set finalList [list ]
foreach selcetion  $selectionList {
    regexp {(\d+):(\d+)} $selection -> start end
    for {set i $start} {$i <= $end} {incr i} {
        if {[lsearch $finalList $i] == -1} {
            lappend finalList $i
        }
    }
}
```

Which of the two methods is faster?

Comment: Don't do both tasks at the same time. Store the ranges (instead of the numbers) in a list and write some code that "inserts" a range. When you have your unique, sorted ranges, make the actual list of numbers. Unless you have many short ranges, this should be a fast mehod.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [time](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/time.htm) command to test the performance of Tcl code. Ensure you place your code in a procedure to gain the benefit of having it byte-compiled then use the time command to run the test a number of times and get an average time per iteration. For instance, here is an example that shows why expr expressions should always be braced.

```
% proc a {} {expr 1 + 2 + 3}
% proc b {} {expr {1 + 2 + 3}}
% time a 1000
4.491 microseconds per iteration
% time b 1000
0.563 microseconds per iteration
```

To deal with the specific task - I would add each new value into an array and let that eat the duplicates and then just turn it into a list at the end.

```
proc getUniques {wantedSize} {
    array set uniques {}
    while {[array size uniques] != $wantedSize} {
         set uniques([getNewValue]) {}
    }
    return [array names uniques]
}
```

Comment: After testing, @siyb's method using `lsort -unique` is the fastest. I chose this answer as the accepted answer, because it gives the tool to test different methods (`time`), which I since used to test other algorithms for other problems.

Answer (score 4):

I also use the `time` command to benchmark. Here is my code, which I added two more methods, one to use `array` and the other uses `struct::set` to eliminate duplicates.

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337534/what-way-is-faster-to-populate-a-list-with-unique-values-in-tcl

package require Tclx
package require struct::set

proc removeDupMethod {selectionList} {
    set finalList [list ]
    foreach selection $selectionList {
        regexp {(\d+):(\d+)} $selection -> start end
        for {set i $start} {$i <= $end} {incr i} {
            lappend finalList $i
        }
    }
    set finalList [lrmdups $finalList]
    return $finalList
}

proc searchBeforInsertMethod {selectionList} {
    set finalList [list ]
    foreach selection $selectionList {
        regexp {(\d+):(\d+)} $selection -> start end
        for {set i $start} {$i <= $end} {incr i} {
            if {[lsearch $finalList $i] == -1} {
                lappend finalList $i
            }
        }
    }
}

proc useArrayMethod {selectionList} {
    array set tally {}
    foreach selection $selectionList {
        regexp {(\d+):(\d+)} $selection -> start end
        for {set i $start} {$i <= $end} {incr i} {
            incr tally($i)
        }
    }
    set finalList [array names tally]
    return $finalList
}

proc useStructSetMethod {selectionList} {
    set finalList {}
    foreach selection $selectionList {
        regexp {(\d+):(\d+)} $selection -> start end
        for {set i $start} {$i <= $end} {incr i} {
            struct::set include finalList $i
        }
    }
    return $finalList
}

# Performs the benchmark on a method
proc bench {methodName} {
    set selectionList {1:10 5:20 10:30 4:30}
    set timeInfo [time {$methodName $selectionList} 1000]
    puts "$methodName - $timeInfo"
}

# main
bench removeDupMethod
bench searchBeforInsertMethod
bench useArrayMethod
bench useStructSetMethod
```

The result:

```
removeDupMethod - 281.961364 microseconds per iteration
searchBeforInsertMethod - 93.984991 microseconds per iteration
useArrayMethod - 122.354889 microseconds per iteration
useStructSetMethod - 576.293311 microseconds per iteration
```

## Discussion

- Your second method, `searchBeforInsertMethod`, is the fastest.
- `useArrayMethod`, which uses an array to ensure uniqueness, comes in second. This is to say that the TCL's built-in list commands are very optimized.
- To my surprise, the `useStructSetMethod` is the slowest. I thought a library command should be optimized, but I was wrong.

## Update

I took Siyb's hint and replace:

```
regexp {(\d+):(\d+)} $selection -> start end
```

with:

```
set range [split $selection :]
set start [lindex $selection 0]
set end [lindex $selection 1]
```

And see a *dramatic* increase in speed:

```
removeDupMethod - 9.337442 microseconds per iteration
searchBeforInsertMethod - 5.528975999999999 microseconds per iteration
useArrayMethod - 6.8120519999999996 microseconds per iteration
useStructSetMethod - 5.774831 microseconds per iteration
useNative - 6.105141 microseconds per iteration
```

Notes

- The fastest is still `searchBeforInsertMethod`, the speed increase is nearly 17 times.
- `useStructSetMethod` now rises to take second place

## Update 2

Per potrzebie's request, I added 5000:6000 to the beginning and the numbers do not change much:

```
removeDupMethod - 10.826106 microseconds per iteration
searchBeforInsertMethod - 6.296769 microseconds per iteration
useArrayMethod - 7.752042 microseconds per iteration
useStructSetMethod - 6.910305999999999 microseconds per iteration
useNative - 7.274724 microseconds per iteration
```

Comment: "This is to say that the TCL's built-in list commands are very optimized" - and/or that arrays have high overhead. `lsearch` is only fastest for short lists, try adding `5000:6000` to the start of `selectionList`.

Comment: Using a `regexp` will be expensive as that shimmers between different formats of string internally (UTF-8 vs direct UNICODE).

Answer (score 2):

I have tried using lsort -unique $list instead of lrmdups. On my box, this is the fastest method:

```
proc useNative {selectionList} {
        foreach selection $selectionList {
            regexp {(\d+):(\d+)} $selection -> start end
            for {set i $start} {$i <= $end} {incr i} {
                lappend finalList $i
            }
        }
        set finalList [lsort -unique $finalList]
        return $finalList
}

removeDupMethod - 171.573 microseconds per iteration
searchBeforInsertMethod - 58.264 microseconds per iteration
useArrayMethod - 96.109 microseconds per iteration
useStructSetMethod - 386.889 microseconds per iteration
useNative - 41.556 microseconds per iteration
```

EDIT: using split instead of the regular expression speeds up things as well (if the regex is actually part of your problem):

```
useNative - 20.938 microseconds per iteration
```

EDIT2: try adding -integer as a lsort parameter, should speed up things a little as well, if your are planning on sorting integers that is

Comment: This is the fastest in town. I agree about regexp as well.